# SQL Query - Why is the outcome different?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I expected the same results but it seems like I'm not understanding why the queries don't give the same results. What is truly the difference between Query 1 vs Query 2 vs Query 3. Query 2 and Query 3 give the same results but Query 1 gives less results.

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID, A.EMPLOYEE_SEQ_ID, B.EMPLOYEE_SEQ_ID, A.EMPLOYEE_ID, A.DEPT_ID, A.SUBDEPT_ID, A.START_DATE, A.END_DATE
FROM [WORKAREA].[DBO].[EMPLOYER] A, [WORKAREA].[DBO].[EMPLOYER] B
    WHERE
        A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID AND
        A.DEPT_ID = B.DEPT_ID AND
        A.SUBDEPT_ID = B.SUBDEPT_ID AND
        A.GENDER = B.GENDER AND
        A.RELATIONSHIP = B.RELATIONSHIP AND
        A.ID <> B.ID AND
        (
            (A.START_DATE BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE) OR
            (A.END_DATE BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE) OR
            (A.START_DATE < B.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE > B.END_DATE) OR
            (A.START_DATE > B.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE < B.END_DATE)
        )
        AND
        (
        A.START_DATE <> B.START_DATE OR
        A.END_DATE <> B.END_DATE
        )
        ORDER BY A.EMPLOYEE_ID, A.DEPT_ID, A.SUBDEPT_ID, A.EMPLOYEE_SEQ_ID, B.EMPLOYEE_SEQ_ID, A.START_DATE, A.END_DATE
```

**VS**

```
SELECT A.EMPLOYEE_ID, A.DEPT_ID, A.SUBDEPT_ID, A.START_DATE, A.END_DATE
FROM [WORKAREA].[DBO].[EMPLOYER] a
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT 1 FROM [WORKAREA].[DBO].[EMPLOYER] b
        WHERE A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID AND
            A.DEPT_ID = B.DEPT_ID AND
            A.SUBDEPT_ID = B.SUBDEPT_ID AND
            A.GENDER = B.GENDER AND
            A.RELATIONSHIP = B.RELATIONSHIP AND
            A.ID <> B.ID AND
            (
                (A.START_DATE BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE) OR
                (A.END_DATE BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE) OR
                (A.START_DATE < B.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE > B.END_DATE) OR
                (A.START_DATE > B.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE < B.END_DATE)
            )
            AND
            (
                A.START_DATE <> B.START_DATE OR
                A.END_DATE <> B.END_DATE
            )
    )
    ORDER BY A.EMPLOYEE_ID, A.DEPT_ID, A.SUBDEPT_ID, A.START_DATE;
```

**VS**

```
SELECT * FROM [WORKAREA].[DBO].[EMPLOYER] A
JOIN [WORKAREA].[DBO].[EMPLOYER] B ON 
    A.EMPLOYEE_ID = B.EMPLOYEE_ID AND
    A.DEPT_ID = B.DEPT_ID AND
    A.SUBDEPT_ID = B.SUBDEPT_ID AND
    A.GENDER = B.GENDER AND
    A.RELATIONSHIP = B.RELATIONSHIP AND
    A.ID <> B.ID
    WHERE
    (
        (A.START_DATE BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE) OR
        (A.END_DATE BETWEEN B.START_DATE AND B.END_DATE) OR
        (A.START_DATE < B.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE > B.END_DATE) OR
        (A.START_DATE > B.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE < B.END_DATE)
    )
    AND
    (
        A.START_DATE <> B.START_DATE OR
        A.END_DATE <> B.END_DATE
    )
    ORDER BY A.EMPLOYEE_ID, A.DEPT_ID, A.SUBDEPT_ID, A.START_DATE;
```

I expected the same results but it seems like I'm not understanding why the queries don't give the same results. What is truly the difference between Query 1 vs Query 2 vs Query 3. Query 2 and Query 3 give the same results but Query 1 gives less results.

Comment: They are fundamentally different. Use modern *join* syntax and it might be more apparent.

Comment: When you join table A to B you get a row from A for every matching row in B. When you check if a row *exists* in table B that's *true* or *false* and a single row from A is returned regardless of how many rows in B match

Comment: @Stu I just looked at the sample of data and did notice why. Thanks!

Comment: i think you mean Query 1 and 3 give same results? because they are mostly the same

Answer (score 0):

there is redundancy of information in the three queries and although they work, the information will not be exact

in the first the following lines can go without ()
(A.START_DATE < B.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE > B.END_DATE) OR
(A.START_DATE > B.START_DATE AND A.END_DATE < B.END_DATE)

in the second there is a subquery that must exist for the query to return a related result
the where braces should go in the join, for good practice

the third query gives you the correct result.